# Insert Date Field to MS SQL from Proc SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, sas, proc-sql

I'd like to insert a date field into a SQL server table form Proc SQL in SAS. Here is my code for Proc SQL:

```
proc sql;
    insert into CFS_SQL.Data_DSB_Raw(sasdatefmt=(TheDate='mmddyy10.'))
    select TheDateIncoming
    from Work.Upload;
quit;
```

According to the SAS help documentation (http://support.sas.com/kb/6/450.html), this should work as long as `TheDateIncoming` also has format `mmddyy10.`. I've verified that the format on `TheDateIncoming` is correct, so I think this should work.

Unfortunately, however, I'm getting a "Value 1 on the SELECT clause does not match the data type of the corresponding column" error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What if you remove that option?

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: What SQL server datatype is TheDate? Is it the FIRST field of Data_DSB_Raw? Is this using ODBC or OLEDB connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annnnnd... solved. It actually had nothing to do with the code. It was a driver problem. Switching to the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 ODBC driver fixed the issue.